# heapq, dealing with same values for two objects?

Tags: python, heap, sliding-tile-puzzle

I found a problem while trying to push objects with same values into heap.

```
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        if neighbor.get_config() not in explored and neighbor.get_config() not in frontier_set:
            print(frontier_heap)
            heapq.heappush(frontier_heap, ((neighbor.get_cost() + calculate_manhattan_dist(neighbor)), neighbor))
            frontier_set.add(neighbor.get_config())
```

I am getting following output:

```
[(12, <__main__.PuzzleState object at 0x008B5EB0>)]

[(10, <__main__.PuzzleState object at 0x008B5E90>), (12, <__main__.PuzzleState object at 0x008B5EB0>)]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/stuff/python/AI/P1/driver_3.py", line 343, in <module>
    print(A_star_search(PuzzleState((6,1,8,4,0,2,7,3,5))))
  File "c:/stuff/python/AI/P1/driver_3.py", line 277, in A_star_search
    heapq.heappush(frontier_heap, ((neighbor.get_cost() + calculate_manhattan_dist(neighbor)), neighbor))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'PuzzleState' and 'PuzzleState'
```

Is there a way to push the object into heap based on the other feature of an object while still saving the object in the heap?

Comment: Have you read the [Basic examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#basic-examples) in the heapq documentation?

Comment: thanks, I didnt realize I can put more than two elements into heap.